# Fingerprint at scale - what is the state of the art?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, deep-learning, supervised-learning, pattern-recognition

I'm working on a problem of fraud detection in account opening. When a new user opens an account, we compare a set of three fingerprints against entries in an existing database.

The existing database has about 100M fingerprints and we need to crosscheck the new entries against these existing ones.

My question is: what is the state of the art of fingerprint for large scaled systems? There are Deep Learning applications already running in production environments? If no, what is the currently used approach to tackle the problem?

Thanks in advance!